# Uncaught TypeError: filesys.existsSync is not a function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

When trying to initialize IOT device using AWS IoT SDK for JavaScript, its giving error

> TypeError: filesys.existsSync is not a function

```
var device = AWSIoTData.device({
    keyPath: "././assets/certificate/xx",
    certPath: "././assets/certificate/xx",
    caPath: "././assets/certificate/xx",
    clientId: "xx",
    host: "xx",
    region: "xx",
    port: 8883,
    debug: true
});
```

How come tls-reader.js has this undefined function?

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to work with aws-iot-sdk with browser this will not work as expected. In your example your trying to access the certificates using path which is a functionality not available on browser runtime. FileSystem is a system module and it's not supported by a browser but supported by node. However you can use to "browserify" get this resolved. Refer to the [sdk documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#browser) for more information.